# C# DTO List that consists of 2 other lists

Tags: c#, asp.net

Firstly, apologies if this seems basic, I am new to C#/dotnet and if the answer to this questions is somewhere obvious please point me in the right direction.

I have a DTO class with the following code

```
public class LessonDetailView : BaseResult
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public List<LessonImagesListView> LessonImages { get; set; }
    public List<LessonInstructionCardListView> InstructionCards { get; set; }
}

public class LessonImagesListView
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ImageDetailView Image { get; set; }
    public LessonImagesListView()
    {
        Image = new ImageDetailView();
    }
}

public class LessonInstructionCardListView
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Instructions { get; set; }
}
```

So I have 2 distinct types of object that I attach to the lesson and send to the frontend.

I will add that in the future I might have 6 different types of object.
These Images, or Instructions are also going to be displayed in a certain order on the front end so instead of sending them all separately I wanted to combine them all and send them in a new List `LessonAssetsListView` for example.

How can i create Lists in a DTO that combine 2 other lists ?
OR ... is this something I even need to do here ... and can i just do all this in my service.

Help appreciated.

Comment: If these types have a common base class (e.g. `ListView`, then use a `List<ListView>`. A common interface works as well: `List<IListView>`. See: [Inheritance - derive types to create more specialized behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/object-oriented/inheritance).

Comment: Why do want to combine them? How would frontend know how to interpret each record if you have a single collection?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply define a type that composes both your existing and send a `List` of them

```
public class LessonAsset 
{
    public LessonImagesListView Image {get;set; }
    public LessonInstructionCardListView Instruction {get;set;}
}
```

and then

```
public class LessonDetailView : BaseResult
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public List<LessonAsset> LessonAssets { get; set; }
}
```